# LLDB get memory address of argv

Tags: c, lldb, argv

I'm reading through Jon Erickson's [Hacking](http://www.nostarch.com/hacking2.htm) and on page 61 there's an example using gdb to explore the array of pointers-to-string stored in `argv`. It looks like when you break at `main` in gdb, the value of `argc` and address of `argv` are part of the log statement. E.g.,

```
Breakpoint 1, main(argc=2, argv=0xbffff894) at convert2.c:14
```

I'm trying to do the same thing with lldb, and while I can use `settings show target.run-args` to get the args, what I really want is the address of `argv`. Is this possible?

Comment: What is 'lldb'?  for argv, the address is passed into the program at main as the second parameter.  Just use that address.  For instance, printf( "%p" argv);

Comment: @user3629249 llvm-based debugger, and the stock debugger on all OS X as of Xcode 6.0 command line tools (it may have been before that, but as recall that was it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ARM and x86_64, it is quite easy: stop at main, and do:

```
(lldb) memory read -t "char *" -c `(int) $arg1` $arg2
```

"memory read -t" is functionally the same as the gdb print's "@" syntax.  Just says "read the memory pointed to by the address passed to the command as an array of the type given by the -t argument"

lldb defines "convenience variables" $arg1, $arg2, etc, which are aliases for the registers that are used to pass the first, second, etc arguments to a function.  You have to be right at the beginning of the function for these to have the correct value, since these are just registers and they will get reused.  32-bit Intel doesn't use registers for argument passing, so you'll have to get them from the stack.

This command uses $arg2, which will hold the argv variable as the memory address to read.

The other interesting thing about this command is it is using lldb's backtick - which means evaluate this argument as an expression - to read the count from the first (argc) argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Just wondering, what if you build in 32-bit mode? How do you know where in the stack to look for the args?

Comment: MacOS X uses the standard i386 ABI.  If you can get access to it, this Tech Note has all these details and many more: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2124/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003391